# Amazon SNS Sample Application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub

I'm new to the Amazon SNS Service, I just subscribed today to begin experimenting with it.  I logged into the Mobile Hub Console, and I created a new project.  I then selected the Push Notifications, for Android, and chose to Build.

In the instructions it says it should be as simple as importing the source project provided in the Build step into Android Studio, and then click Debug app.

When I do this, I immediately get a NullPointerException: null error in the event log of Android Studio.  I am trying to load the MySampleApp onto an emulator to test how the push notifications work, but I can't even get the app to run due to this error.

When I click on the error in the Event Log, a pop-up shows the following details.  I'm not sure what to do, as the instructions don't indicate anything other than Import the project into Android Studio and click Debug app.

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidSessionInfo.isEmbeddable(AndroidSessionInfo.java:62)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getOldSessionTarget(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:307)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:279)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:201)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:58)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:94)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:396)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$5.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:332)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple quick things to check...

1. Are you running the latest version of Android Studio (e.g., 1.5.1)?
2. Did you choose to "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc)" in Android Studio? The sample app is a gradle project, so it must be imported.
3. Have you been able to launch apps on your AVD before? For example, if you create a new Android app project, can you launch it successfully on your AVD from Android Studio?
4. Do you see any gradle build errors in the gradle console window on the bottom of Android Studio?

Comment: I noticed this morning that my Android Studio prompted me to upgrade.  After upgrading to the newest version 1.5.1, I am now able to build and debug the sample app.  Thanks for the help!